# sitecore scheduled publishing multiple targets

Tags: sitecore, publishing

I'm trying to get the scheduled publishing working with sitecore and i'm having issues.  The problem is that I have multiple targets I need to publish to and they reside on separate servers.  I can set the web.config to do a schedule publish on the server the web.config resides on, however, how can I publish to an external server at the same time?

Also, I've just tried publishing to one target with the following changes in my web.config:

```
 <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
    <param desc="source database">master</param>
    <param desc="target database">web</param>
    <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">smart</param>
    <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
  </agent>
```

The interval is greater than the scheduling frequency(00:05:00), however, the content doesn't seem to get published.

This is what I get in my log:

INFO  Scheduler - Skipping inactive agent: Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent

Not sure why it is still being seen as inactive.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The INFO message you are seeing is stating that your PublishAgent task is still set to an interval of 00:00:00.

INFO Scheduler - Skipping inactive agent: Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent

To resolve this I would first start by verifying your configuration is actually updated on the server and that it is not being changed by a Sitecore Include config file.  The easiest way to check this would be to use the Sitecore ShowConfig utility http://sitecoreinstancename.local/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx.  This will show you the active config with all of the patched in elements.

Verify that your PublishAgent is still set to 00:00:00 and then update the appropriate configuration files.

In order to publish to an additional publishing database, just add in an additional agent such as below.  This will schedule a smart publish to web every 15 minutes and a smart publish to a target database called production every 18 minutes.

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
   <param desc="source database">master</param>
   <param desc="target database">web</param>
   <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">smart</param>
   <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:18:00">
   <param desc="source database">master</param>
   <param desc="target database">Production</param>
   <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">smart</param>
   <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>
```